# Jquery multiple ID selector doesn't work

Tags: jquery-selectors

I tried this script but didn't work for the second given ID;
The both element are inside an iframe

```
<script> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

        $("#subscribe_newsletter, #close_bar").each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
                alert("with each");
                $.cookie( "nl_cookie" , 1  , { path: "/" } );
                $("#footer_accept_newsletter").hide("slow");
            }); 
        });  
        cookieValue =  $.cookie("nl_cookie" , { path: "/" });

        if(!cookieValue){  
            $("#footer_accept_newsletter").removeClass("hidden");
        }
    });
</script>
```

I tried also the following code but no success;

```
$("#subscribe_newsletter, #close_bar").click(function(){
    $.cookie( "nl_cookie" , 1  , { path: "/" } );
    $("#footer_accept_newsletter").hide("slow");
});
```

Comment: Try this : `jQuery.each(["#subscribe_newsletter", "#close_bar"], function(i, id) { $(id).click(function() { ... }) })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work for me

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#segement1, #segement2, #segement3").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
  });
});
```

Check it [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/99991xqd/)